# Class D amplifier - equation for peak current?

Tags: current, class-d

I'm trying to spec a power supply for a class D amplifier IC. I have figured out the maximum RMS current draw by taking the RMS power rating of the amp, increasing that to compensate for efficiency losses, then applying: $$P = I^2R$$
Where \$R\$ is the speaker impedance.

However my power supply needs to be spec'd for the *peak* current, not the RMS current, right? So, assuming the above approach is correct, how do I get the peak current draw of a class D amp?

Comment: I'm not sure what best practice is when it comes to speakers, as their impedance is very strongly frequency-dependent; "8-ohm" or whatever the speaker is specified to is an approximation at best, and not a very good one either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there is no such simple relationship. Speakers and the amplifier (and the filters) form a resonant system, and that can introduce much higher voltages into the system than supplied by the power supply.

However, it doesn't really matter:

The peak power consumption isn't something that you need to *supply*, but a design factor that you can choose. It's up to you, within the limits of not damaging your speakers or the switching transistors, to decide how much peak current your amplifier system needs to be able to draw.

For example, you might decide that you want your power supply to deliver enough power for the max RMS power consumption of the amplifier (that's not a "must"! You can built an amplifier that could draw more power than the supply can offer, and then use it at less-than-maximum-volume). That's easy, you just use \$P=U\cdot I\$ and solve for \$I\$, and get a \$U\$ voltage power supply that can at least supply \$I\$ current continously.

Then you decide that at that (undubitably loud) setting, you still want to be able to, for a short term of \$t=0.5\,\text{s}\$, supply more power, say four times as much. So, that'd be a current factor of four. You decide that you need to supply half of that by having half of the appropriate charge (\$I\cdot t = Q\$) in a capacitor, and overdimensioning your power supply by a factor of 2. (just rough numbers; none of this takes efficiency or the exponential discharge curve of a capacitor into account)

In any case, the speaker impedance doesn't come into play here, anyways: your current goes through the switching transistors of your class-D amplifier, so your amplifier manufacturer is in charge of definining a maximum power and/or current, anyway.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Say I do want my supply to deliver the max rated RMS power. If I simply solve P=UI for the RMS power, will the current figure I get actually be sufficient? Shouldn't I solve P=UI for the peak power, not the RMS power?

Comment: that's exactly what the second half of my answer is about.

Answer (score 1):

The peak current from RMS is just 1.414 x RMS, but a Class  D Amp is really a Buck-Boost SMPS.

Check out and understand all 3 parts to this series. Then try  the Analog Power Design tools.
https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/switch-mode-power-supply-current-sensing-part-2-where-to-place-the-sense-resistor.html

I believe you biggest current spike will be for the Bass speakers.  This will be in CCM mode with high duty cycle.  But the inductor current must ramp up and down with PWM to achieve this peak current.  So at a minimum I suggest 1.5 x RMS and consider the inductor is rated for 2x RMS  current without saturating.

If you plan on using a SMPS to power this  class D Amp the impedance and ripple at both frequency rates and use some simulation tools like Falstad to model the DCR,L, ESR C and choose SPDT Switch and choose the Ron resistance to test for resonance or export into the frequency domain applet and examine the frequency attenuation of the LPF filter.

But that’s all I’ll say for now.

Comment: Thanks Sunnyskyguy for this real world advice. So the actual current draw of the amp could be 1.5-2 times higher than the RMS current?

Comment: No, it is written about amplifier peak output current, NOT the input one. Amplifier input current flows from power supply to amplifier, amplifier output current flows fom amplifier to speakers.

Comment: Input current can be smaller if voltage is larger than needed at max current with losses estimated.

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR**

The standard RMS to Peak conversion factor of 1.414 is a good starting point for the peak current calculation.

**Details**

The Class-D amplifier IC is known i.e. the author has selected the amplifier and the question is only related to the characteristics of a suitable power supply.

The safe operating limits for a Class-D IC are determined by the manufacturer. The manufacturer's data sheet will provide the maximum power out, maximum power supply voltage, minimum load impedance, etc. Typically a rating for peak currents will not be explicitly stated for normal operation.

Current generation Class-D amplifier ICs will also include internal protection circuitry to detect operation outside of safe operating conditions such as a thermal overload or fault conditions that would draw excessive current from the power supply.

When a designer creates an amplifier they determine the operation within the manufacturer's limits. In this case the output power and associated supply voltage are known therefore an RMS current has been calculated.

An IC part number has not been given. Obviously it is not possible to consult the relevant data sheet. Therefore a sample data sheet is used to outline an answer.

The question asked is:-
how do I get the peak current draw of a class D amp?   `

The Texas Instruments,  50W stereo Class D amplifier [TAS5828M](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tas5828m.pdf) data sheet will be used for illustration.

Section 6.1 Absolute Maximum Ratings, PVDD Supply Voltage maximum is 30V and the power supply under all conditions should never exceed this voltage.

Section 6.5 Electrical Characteristics, Protection, OCEthresh, Over-Current Error Threshold (Speaker Current) ranges from 7.5Amps to 8.5Amps with a typical value of 8Amps. For the manufacturer's minimum 2 Ohm load in mono mode the power limits (I2R) are 112W (7.5 x 7.5 x 2) to 144.5W (8.5 x 8.5 x 2) with a typical value of 128W (8 x 8 x2).

The overcurrent protection will trigger "... starts shutdown process less than 100ns once peak-current detector is over Overcurrent Threshold (list in Electrical Characteristics - OCETHRES ). The shutdown speed depends on a number of factors, such as the impedance of the short circuit, supply voltage, and switching frequency."

Section 1 Features, includes "1 × 100 W, 1.0 Mode (2-Ω, 23 V, THD+N=1%)" This is below the minimum speaker over current threshold. But the manufacturer provides information regarding other operating conditions.

Section 6.3 Recommended Operating Conditions, V(power), power supply inputs, PVDD maximum supply Voltage is 26.4V and is the upper design limit for the power supply. The recommended power supply voltage is actually given as a range from 4.5V to 26.4V and will be one of the factors that determines output power.

Due to different modulation modes there are two characteristic curves therefore two figures for each range. Figures 6-10, 6-29 Output Power vs Supply Voltage provides a graphical answer to the RMS output power for a 4 Ohm load over this voltage range. The other figures (6-11, 6-12, 6-30, 6-31) illustrate higher value loads.

This is a Stereo amplifier that can operate in bridge mode as a single channel amplifier for higher output power into a lower value load. Figures 6-48, 6-65 Output Power vs Supply Voltage provides a graphical answer to the RMS output power for a 2 Ohm load over this voltage range. The other figures (6-49, 6-50, 6-66, 6-66) illustrate higher value loads.

These figures provide maximum output power is provided for 1% and 10% distortion up to 120W at 1% and 160W at 10% or for the 2 Ohm load 7.7A at 1% or an approximation of 8.9A for 10% distortion. Under these conditions the Over-Current Error Threshold (Speaker Current) can be exceeded. Therefore the power supply should not be rated for a higher peak current than Over-Current Error Threshold (Speaker Current) for mono or twice the channel current in stereo mode.

The question is the peak draw current and not the RMS value. At less than the peak rated output power Section 9 Application and Implementation, 9.1.1 Inductor Selections, Page 75, provides the overview of the maximum current. Of the three only Ipeak_output_power is related to the the calculated RMS current. The other two possibilites are for the non-linear conditions of peak clipping and peak power up i.e. at start up when power is first applied.

Below the Over-Current Error Threshold (Speaker Current) discussed above the standard RMS to Peak current conversion can apply. For an audio amplifier specifying the power supply for the higher current requirement of sustained, non-linear clipping is pointless.

Of course the data sheets for the various Class-D amplifier ICs will vary and examination of all the available literature is required. In the case of the TAS5828M the [Advanced Features](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa846/slaa846.pdf) document needs to be consulted for additional information on the performance of the device under varying voltage conditions. This could become an important factor if the supply is a battery or underated power supply relying on capacitors for audio peaks.

Another factor that should be examined it the reponse of the amplifier to thermal limits and throttling. Again a case of examining all the available literature such as the TAS5828M Advanced Features document.

Once the RMS and peak currents requirements are known a power supply can be constructed. If an underated power supply with capacitors for audio peaks is used then confirm the Section 6.5 Electrical Characteristics, PSRR Power supply rejection ratio provides satisfactory performance. Obviously for a suitable, fully regulated, power supply this should not be an issue.

**Summary**

For operation at the amplifier perfomance limits consult the manufacturer's data sheet otherwise the standard RMS to peak current conversion factor of 1.414 should be adequate.